# Skype4Com Get Friends Contacts?

Tags: class, friend, skype4com

I have the following code in C# that add items "friends contacts" to checkListItem UI Control
But the question is what is the diff between DisplayName and FullName properties in Friend class????
please answer me :)

foreach (User contact in skype.Friends)
{

```
  contactItem = new ContactItem(contact.Handle,contact.Handle + " is a " + contact.DisplayName);

  ContactsList.Items.Add(contactItem);

  contactItem = new ContactItem(contact.Handle, contact.Handle + " is a " + contact.FullName);

  ContactsList.Items.Add(contactItem);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short:

`User.FullName` - is the text the user entered in his profile

`User.DisplayName` - is the text from your contact's list, it's filled when you choose to rename a contact.

---

A quote from http://dev.skype.com/desktop-api-reference#OBJECTS:

> `FULLNAME` – user’s full name, for example: `USER pamela FULLNAME Jane Doe` .
>
> `DISPLAYNAME` – By default this property is empty. If a value is assigned to this property
>    with `SET <skypename> DISPLAYNAME <value>` then that value will be displayed in Skype UI instead of user’s `FULLNAME`